# Stopping the activity from recreating when resumed

Tags: android

I got two activities. When I jump from first to second activity and then come back to first one, the activity gets recreated in some phones. Can anyone tell me how to prevent it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can prevent it. If you have some state to save, consider saving it. If you need things to keep running in the background, consider using a `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop the recreating from an App, but you can save your state in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and retrieve the state in `onCreate(Bundle)` or `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to store a listview? I have seen the tutorials for using savedInstanceState but its a bundle only and I can't store listview.

Comment: First, save content/values of your listview, not listview itself. Second, retrieve the values that stored in bundle, then reconstruct the listview.

Answer (score 1):

It's the intended behaviour, and you shouldn't be trying to stop it. But, as mentioned by gnobal, you will need to save the state, and recreate your data to handle these situations properly.

Some phones with low memory, will always do that. A good way to test your implementation is to go to "**Developer options**" and enable "**Don't keep activities**".